# "Add RestAPI Client" missing on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, swagger

On VS 2015 we have "*Add RestAPI client*" but it does not exist for VS 2017.
Is there any solution to have it on VS 2017?

**Note:** I don't want to install 3rd party (not MS) components like AuthoRest or Swagger Codegen.

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen that menu. Try to figure out which extension or template or whatever installed that menu item.

Comment: Menu is available on VS 2015 after Azure SDK installation. The "same" SDK already installed on VS 2017 (acording to MS).

To see the menu right click on 'solution explorer' and select 'add'.

Answer (score 1):

I see it on VS2017.  And just for your info, AutoREST is a Microsoft tool, and it is what the Add RestAPI client uses under the covers.

Comment: Thanks for replay.
What version of VS 2017 do you have?
May be you know which extension is it?

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Darrel again

Your comment points me to right direction:

This menu item visibility depemds on platform.
It's visible for traditional framework app, but not for NET Core.

Another one inconsistancy from Microsoft?
I don't know and I don't see any reason why it's not available for net core 2.

Cheers

Comment: @OlegSusarov  I suspect that the Add Rest Client option  may not have been updated recently.  The AutoRest team have been working furiously on adding all kinds of features to AutoRest and the VS Code plugin.  I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue for getting AutoRest to work on .Net Core 2 projects - 
https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2023 (old), https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2450 (current)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Azure SDK For Visual Studio

Comment: I have switched to using the Azure/autorest on github which is more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60431700/1831734  (install ASP.Net and Web development or packets related to this)