# Visual Studio "REST Api Client" missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, visual-studio-2017

Hello I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community (15.9.20)

The option **Add->REST API Client...** is missing.

I have tried using .Net Framework 4.6, 4.7 same as Console /WinForms/Class Library projects.

I have also googled this but there's no clear info how to fix it.

[image: REST Api Client option is missing]

Comment: I'm not familiar with that button. Perhaps it was being provided by an extension? Do you have a working server that has it? Can you compare the installed extensions in each? Perhaps your working machine has [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChristianResmaHelle.ApiClientCodeGenerator)?

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897549/add-restapi-client-missing-on-visual-studio-2017.  Generally, those things are just templates that something installs (either during the main install, during the install of an add-on, or directly, just getting the template from someplace like the marketplace)

Comment: @mason no its not from extension I have it by default in my workplace. Only difference is installed packets or enterprise/community version.

Comment: @mrR Can you restart your VS and check if that fixes your issue?

Comment: @MKR i found solution in Flydog57 comment url

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution in link from @Flydog57 comment

I had to install following WorkLoad and now I am able to use "REST Api Client" in all of Console/Class Library /Win Forms App Projects
[image: REST API Client - Missing workload]